# Allowing multiple arguments in any order in PHP

Tags: php, arguments

I have a function which takes in about 10 arguments, in which most of them are optional. I was wondering if I could implement it in such a way that the user of the function does not need to bother with the order of the parameters.
For example:

```
public function foo($arg1, $arg2, $arg3='',$arg4='', $arg5='', $arg6='', $arg7=''){}
```

Now, when I use this function I can simply

```
$this->foo($arg1val, $arg2val, $arg6val);
```

Is there a way in php to do so?

Here is how I implemented this:
I've listed the parameters accepted by the function in the API, so the user can pass the parameters in any order in an array with key=>value pairs.

For example:

```
public function argumentsFilter($origParams, $newParams){
    $tmpArr = array();
        foreach ($origParams as $origKey){
        foreach($newParams as $newKey => $newVal){
                    if($newKey == $origKey){
                $tmpArr[$origKey] = $newVal;
                    }
        }
        if(empty($tmpArr[$origKey])){
                    $tmpArr[$origKey] = '';
        }
           }
        return $tmpArr;
}

public function foo($arg1, $arg2, $arg=array()){

    $validArgList = array('arg3', 'arg4', 'arg5', 'arg6', 'arg7');

    $correctedArgList = $this->argumentsFilter($validArgList, $arg);   

}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: There are [tricks](http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/04/22/php-named-parameters/) you can try, but IMO passing an array is the cleanest way to do this. 

If you want true support for named [parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter) like some other languages have (eg: Python, C#), it probably isn't coming [any time soon](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22216)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 parameters for a function is clearly too much. Pass arrays instead:

```
function foo(array $params) {
    $defaults = array('foo' => true, 'bar' => false, ...);
    $params = array_intersect_key($params, $defaults) + $defaults;

    // work with $params['foo']
    // maybe extract($params)
}
```

This example shows a function that accepts an arbitrary number of "named parameter" in any order, filters invalid values and establishes defaults values.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, since php doesn't support named arguments.

You have 2 choices: to use array or to redesign your function so it has fewer parameters (the latter is preferred).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, but I recommend this method:

```
function doSomething($required, /*optional*/ $arguments = array()) {
    $arguments = array_merge(array(
        // set defaults
        "argument" => "default value", 
    ), $arguments); 

    var_dump($arguments);
}
```

It is very clean and easy to understand.